# How can i put html inside javascript varaible

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I have this dirty way of coding function which returns HTML.

Is there any better way i can do it.

I am having hard time in inserting variables inside it and it looks very dirty

```
function getTemplate (model, id) {
    model = "Test";
    id = 5;
    return '<div>' +
           '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" title="View"' +
           'ng-click="openTab(panes[1], "' + model + '", "' + id + '")">' +
           '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>' +
           '</button>' +
           '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" title="Edit"' +
           'ng-click="editModal(model, id)">' +
           '<em class="fa fa-pencil"></em>' +
           '</button>' +
           '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" title="Delete"' +
           'ng-click="deleteEntry(id, model)">' +
           '<em class="fa fa-trash"></em>' +
           '</button>' +
           '</div>';
 }
```

EDIT:

I am using angular UI Grid . I am rendering these buttons inside column. which needs cellTemplate in Html

Comment: What are you doing with the HTML? Is this used with ```ng-bind-html```?

Comment: [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)?

Comment: @MichaelWilson This html is used in my grid column to render view, edit delete button. i am using ui Gird

Comment: This scenario predominantly gave angular team the idea for directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am having hard time in inserting variables inside it and it looks
>   very dirty

Using $templateRequest, you can load a template by it’s URL without having to embed it into a string. If the template is already loaded, it will be taken from the cache.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $templateRequest, $sce, $compile){
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.getTemplate = function (model, id) {

      // Make sure that no bad URLs are fetched. If you have a static string like in this
      // example, you might as well omit the $sce call.
      var templateUrl = $sce.getTrustedResourceUrl('nameOfTemplate.html');

      $templateRequest(templateUrl).then(function(template) {
          // template is the HTML template as a string
          $scope.model = "Test";
          $scope.id = 5;
          // Let's put it into an HTML element and parse any directives and expressions
          // in the code. (Note: This is just an example, modifying the DOM from within
          // a controller is considered bad style.)
          $compile($("#my-element").html(template).contents())($scope);
      }, function() {
          // An error has occurred
      });
    };
});
```

Be aware that this is the manual way to do it, and whereas in most cases the preferrable way would be to define a directive that fetches the template using the templateUrl property.

Further, you may bind the variables straightaway since they'd be in the same scope.

Here's the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/EttmRxVzmp5OMXBA2f16?p=preview)

Comment: can i load directive inside angualr ui grid cellTemplate

Comment: Yes you can load a directive inside such template. Here's the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/EttmRxVzmp5OMXBA2f16?p=preview)